# git lfs as content manager

Tags: git, garbage-collection, git-lfs, gitlab-ce

I have a scenario to use git lfs as a content manager.

My plan was to do a test something like that :

```
                                            master   images    combined
init lfs                                     (1)
create images branch                                   (2)
add 2 files                                            (3)
edit 2 files                                           (4)
edit 2 files                                           (5)
edit 2 files                                           (6)
create branch from master                                        (7)
combine images to combines as 1 commit                           (8)
delete images branch                                    -
merge combined to master                     (10)
```

after all of that if the GC runs correctly all the changed files of branch images must get deleted.

Am I correct? Because the GC of lfs have to delete all unreferenced images, so the branch has been deleted so the commits must get removed also.

P.S. the history of the project shows only 2 commits after all the above

**UPDATE**

I deleted the project and after the gc run the space has been removed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the intermediate files become unreferenced by any git reference - which is a branch (local or remote) or tag - in your git history then the `git-lfs` files become eligible for deletion.

However unlike git which automatically GC's after some operations, `git-lfs` doesn't do this automatically (or at least it didn't last time I knew, I've been out of the loop for a little while). Instead, you need to run `git lfs prune` which will delete files which are unreferenced.

Note, however, that because `git lfs prune` is designed to generally recover disk space, it may also delete local versions of files which ARE referenced in your git repo, but not by recent branches (provided they've been pushed to your main remote so don't only exist locally). See `git lfs prune --help` for more details.

HTH

Comment: I have used the `git lfs prune` locally and cleared the storage on .git folder that had to do, but that isn't the issue here. The issue is that the `/mnt/storage/lfs-storage` on gitlab-ce server haven't cleared yet from the unreferenced files.

Comment: OK if you've pushed the files then that's another issue. Pruning content on the server is entirely vendor-dependent, so that's a question for GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

most probably the gitlab-ce didn't removed all the references for the commits, try again the example but don't mer